# Uso del tiempo del futuro vs la condicional

Tags: tiempos-verbales, condicional, futuro

> > "No supo explicar por qué no iría a la excursión el próximo fin de semana".

Por qué usa la condicional en vez del futuro?

> > "No estoy segura, por eso le dije que tendrá unos 40 años."

Por qué usa el futuro en vez de la condicional?

> > No estoy segura, pero creo que tendrá unos 40 años.

Por qué usa el futuro en vez de la condicional?

> > Imaginó que al año siguiente, conseguiría un premio en los campeonatos.

Por qué usa la condicional en vez del futuro perfecto?

Eses frases no son míos. Son de Josefa Martin Garcia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tanto el condicional como el futuro refieren a acciones que acaecen posteriormente a algún tiempo.  Lo que les diferencia es el punto de referencia que usan.

El futuro tiene como punto de referencia ahora mismo.  Es decir, si digo, *imagino que ella viajará a Corea*, se entiende que en algún momento entre justo ahora y un tiempo indefinido posterior a ahora, ella va a viajar a Corea.

El condicional tiene como su punto de referencia algún momento en el pasado.  Es decir, si digo *imaginé que ella viajaría a Corea*, se entiende que en algún momento entre cuando lo imaginé y un tiempo indefinido posterior a *entonces*, ella o hizo, está haciendo, o hará su viaje (porque el período de tiempo posterior al año pasado incluye los últimos meses pasados, ahora mismo, y los meses que vendrán).

No es posible decir *imagino que ella viajaría a Corea* porque es imposible incluir un tiempo pasado.<sup>1</sup>  Si ya hiciese su viaje, habríamos dicho *imagino que ella ha viajado a Corea* y no tendríamos por qué usar el futuro.  De igual forma, no tiene mucha lógica decir *imaginaba que ella viajará a Corea*, porque seguramente en el momento en que lo imaginábamos, el tiempo entre entonces y el presente de ahora también quedaba incluido en el período del viaje.

Tu segunda oración para mí queda mal escrita, debió ser «No estoy segura, por eso le dije que tendría unos 40 años», pero es frecuente en el habla cotidiano cambiar los ejes temporales en el medio de una oración aunque se debe evitarlo en la escritura.

Ello puede ser por las razones que mencioné arriba, pero también hay otro uso común del futuro y condicional que algunos han llamado el modo potencial.  En este uso, el futuro y el condicional tienen significado del presente o del pasado, pero añadiendo la idea de probabilidad: ¿Dónde está mi perro? Estará afuera (probablemente está afuera). Más probablemente ejemplifican este uso, pero siguen regidos por los tiempos. *Le dije que tendría (que probablemente tenía)*, o *creo que tendrá (que probablemente tiene)*. Hay falta de concordancia temporal decir una frase como *Le dije que probablemente tiene*.

---

<sup>1. Siempre que hablamos del valor indicativo del condicional que es una conjugación que varía tanto en modalidad como en temporalidad.  Sí se podría decir *imagino que ella viajaría a Corea* si después se añadiese *si tuviese el dinero*, pero en tal caso, el uso del condicional es perdiferente del que tratamos aquí.</sup>

Comment: Interesantísima explicación, pero dos cosas. En el último párrafo, primera línea: **escrita**. La otra: ¿Por qué se podría considerar mal escrita esa oración en el último párrafo? La explicación (si no estoy mal) está en los anteriores párrafos, pero no la logro captar.

Comment: Al principio tuve «Tu segundo ejemplo» y no lo cambié, gracias.  Hay dos posibles interpretaciones de la oración, ambas válidas y ambas obligan condicional.  Si digo «No estoy seguro, por eso le dije que tendrá unos 40 años», es imposible que haya sabido el momento de ahora («tendrá» significando desde ahora en adelante) ya que lo dije en el pasado.  Por eso es necesario incluir el período entre cuando lo dije y ahora, solo posible con tendría.

Comment: @David La otra interpretación es lo que he visto llamado el modo potencial.  En tales casos, el futuro y el condicional tienen significado del presente o del pasado, pero añadiendo la idea de probabilidad: *¿Dónde está mi perro?  Estará afuera (probablemente está afuera)*.  La segunda y tercera oración más probablemente ejemplifican este uso, pero siguen regidos por los tiempos.  *Le dije que tendría (que probablemente tenía)*, o *creo que tendrá (que probablemente tiene*.  Hay falta de concordancia temporal decir una frase como *Le dije que probablemente tiene*.